# Как создать папку средствами c++

Tags: c++, c, файловая-система

Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет сохранять файлы следующим образом.

Проверить, существует ли папка `"1"` и если нет, то создать папку `"1"` и затем положить туда картинку `test_1`, проверить существует ли папка `"N"`, если нет, то создать и положить туда картинку `test_N`.

Comment: Тебе нужен boost::filesystem.

Comment: Вам нужно совсем-совсем средствами C++ (стандарт и не более) или функции POSIX тоже устроят?

Comment: @Harry имхо boost::filesystem предпочтительней POSIX. Еще вчера это почти было в стандарте =)

Comment: @mrFieldy Тогда уж предпочтительнее стандартный `filesystem` - зачем boost дергать - это все-таки внешняя библиотека...

Comment: @Harry в последний момент его не приняли в стандарт и решили оставить в бусте.

Comment: @mrFieldy Т.е. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), когда пишут *"he filesystem library was originally developed as boost.filesystem, was published as the technical specification ISO/IEC TS 18822:2015, and finally merged to ISO C++ as of C++17."* - беззастенчиво врут?...

Comment: @Harry возможно вру я (очень на это надеюсь). Пошёл разбирается в вопросе. Я почему-то был уверен что пропоузл с filesystem в последний момент отъехал и продолжаю использовать в своих проектах бустовскую реализацию.

Comment: @mrFieldy Harry всё верно говорит https://isocpp.org/std/status

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Начнем с простого пути :)

[`stat`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/stat) из `<sys/stat.h>` для проверки существования файла/каталога.
[`mkdir`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/mkdir) для создания каталога.

Откровенно говоря, буду удивлен, если какой-то компилятор их не имеет.

Но если даже это рассматривается как измена чистому C++ - то в C++17 реализована масса [функциональности для работы с файлами](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). Проверка существования - с помощью [`exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists), создание каталога - [`create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory).